# Matrix inverses on matlab: are pinv and ./ related?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, inverse

I faced with two actual implementations of the same problem, and need some help to find which one is correct.

Let K be an non-square $m \times n$ matrix (a product of two eigenvalues vectors), B an $m \times n$ matrix, and $\lambda$ an regularization term $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. The solution of the equation:

$(K+\lambda) x = B$

can be given by $x = K^{-1} B$, correct?

How are the following matlab implementations related?

```
x = pinv(K + lambda)*B
```

and

```
x = K ./ (K + lambda)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by adding a number $\lambda$ to a matrix $K$?

Comment: 1) Don't you want to solve the problem $\min_x\|B-Kx\|_2^2+\lambda^2\|x\|_2^2$ instead? If this is so, you probably want to do `x=[K;lambda*eye(n)]\[B;zeros(n,1)]`. 2) `pinv` and `./` perform something completely different; see `help pinv` and `help rdivide`. 3) It is a waste to compute an inverse or pseudo-inverse to solve a linear system (or a least squares problem). In most cases, you can simply use the "backslash" operator (as above); see `help mldivide`.

Answer (score 0):

The properly formed linear system is
$$ 
\left( \mathbf{K} + \lambda \, \mathbf{I}_{n} \right) x = B
$$
Define the matrix 
$$
 \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{K} + \lambda\, \mathbf{I}_{n}
$$
and the solution vector can be expressed in terms of the pseudoinverse 
$$
 x = \mathbf{A}^{+} B
$$
which is encapsulated by the MATLAB function `pinv`.

If the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ were nonsingular (square, full rank), you could solve it with `x = B./A`

The pseudoinverse will always work, and will be the only choice if the target matrix is not square, or rank deficient. It will also provide the most accurate answer when the matrix is nonsingular and poorly conditioned.

In the special case of the square, nonsingular, well-conditioned matrix, use the `./` construct.

Comment: The `./` operator does termwise division, which is not what we want. You might be mixing it up with the backslash operator `\ ` , which solves linear systems.